# Logic App Function to remove file extension

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app in Azure. The trigger is to check when an email arrives into a specific folder in a mailbox. An email may contain 1 or more attachments.
Once triggered, I have an HTTP request that gets sent to a SOAP service. The idea is that I want to check if the filename exists at the SOAP Service.

Its all working perfectly, with the exception, when I reference the filename from the trigger, it includes the file extension. I need to somehow ignore the ".PDF" part of the filename

Below is the XML I post to the SOAP service. Lets say the filename is 12345.pdf, then I need /UniversalEvent/Event/ContextCollection/Context/Value to = "12345" and not "12345.pdf":

```
<UniversalEvent xmlns="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11" version="1.1">
    <Event>
        <DataContext>
            <DataTargetCollection>
                <DataTarget>
                    <Type>ForwardingShipment</Type>
                </DataTarget>
        </DataTargetCollection>
        </DataContext>
        <EventTime>@{utcNow()}</EventTime>
        <EventType>Z77</EventType>
        <EventReference>Requesting Shipment ID</EventReference>
        <IsEstimate>false</IsEstimate>
        <ContextCollection>
            <Context>
                <Type>HAWBNumber</Type>
                <Value>@{items('For_each')?['name']}</Value>
            </Context>
            
        </ContextCollection>
</Event>
</UniversalEvent>
```

do you have any suggestions on what function to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the expression `@{items('For_each')?['name']}` in your xml to:

```
@{substring(items('For_each')?['name'], 0, indexOf(items('For_each')?['name'], '.'))}
```